# Can't add a probability-curve on the histogram

Tags: r, histogram, lattice, normal-distribution

I'm trying do display multiple histograms with one plot with the lattice-package.

That's my code so far:

```
histogram(~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7 + X8 + X9 + X10, data=mydata, 
      type = "density",layout=c(5,2),
      panel=function(x, ...) {
        panel.histogram(x, ...)
        panel.mathdensity(dmath=dnorm, col="black",
                          args=list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)), ...)
      })
```

The problem is, that it won't plot the probability-curve. It doesn't give me an error back, so the code looks good, I think.

I also tried it with only one variable and it didn't work either:

```
histogram(~ X1, data=mydata, 
  type = "density",layout=c(5,2),
  panel=function(x, ...) {
    panel.histogram(x, ...)
    panel.mathdensity(dmath=dnorm, col="black",
                      args=list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)), ...)
  })
```

Does anyone see an error in my code? Or could be something wrong in my data?

I'm glad for any advice!

Comment: We can really only help you if you make your example code reproducible. Otherwise we have to guess at the structure of your data. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276 how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that your data contain missing values?

```
# Create example data (no missings)
mydata <- data.frame(X1 = rpois(1000, 12), X2 = rnorm(1000, 12, sqrt(12)))

# Create some missing (NA) entries
mydata2 <- mydata
mydata2[sample(seq_len(nrow(mydata2)), 10), 1] <- NA
```

Using the above `mydata2` object in the histogram function produces no density plot for `X1`, since `mean` and `sd` return `NA`. Adding `na.rm = TRUE` to both those functions will return values that `panel.mathdensity` can use:

```
histogram(~ X1 + X2, data=mydata2, 
      type = "density",layout=c(1,2),
      panel=function(x, ...) {
        panel.histogram(x, ...)
        panel.mathdensity(dmath=dnorm, col="black",
# Add na.rm = TRUE to mean() and sd()
                          args=list(mean=mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
                                    sd=sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)), ...)
      })
```

[image: histogram with density]

Answer (score 0):

Without your data it is hard to help you.

This is a simple example, maybe can help you. I try to keep your settings and correct some ones.

```
library(lattice)

dat <- data.frame(X1 = rnorm(10000),Y1 =rnorm(10000))
histogram(~X1+Y1,
          data = dat,
          main=list(
            label="Main plot title",
            cex=1.5),
          xlab=list(
            label="Custom x-axis label",
            cex=0.75),
          ylab=list(
            label="Your Y label ",
            cex=1.2),
          scales=list(cex=0.5),
          layout = c(1,2),
          par.settings = list(
                              type = "density",
                              panel=function(x, ...) {
                                panel.histogram(x, ...)
                                panel.mathdensity(dmath=dnorm, col="black",
                                                  args=list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x)), ...)
                              })
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't work. I can't see a probability curve on the image you posted?