# Add curve to Lattice barchart

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I hope the question is correctly posted. It is probably trivial but I am still not able to answer. I checked several options, included the info contained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13723060/cant-add-a-probability-curve-on-the-histogram), but with no fortune. Perhaps, I am still not used to Lattice commands, or the problem is actually not relevant.

I would overlap a barchart with a curve, such as (let's say) a normal standard distribution curve or the density distribution of the data.

Please consider the following data as example, representing the results of several die rolls:

```
e11 <- data.frame(freq = rep(seq(1, 6, 1), c(53, 46, 42, 65, 47, 44)))

plot_e11 <- barchart(e11,
            horizontal = FALSE,
            type = "density",
            main = "Die results frequencies",
            panel = function(x, ...){
                    panel.barchart(x, ...)
                    panel.abline(densityplot(e11$freq))})
print(plot_e11a)
```

It returns the normal barchart instead of the expected result.

[image: normal barchart]

How can I add a curve to the barchart, such as the one in the following example?

```
plot_e11b <- densityplot(e11$freq,
                     plot.points = FALSE)
```

[image: density plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`panel.abline` is the wrong panel function.

> `panel.abline` adds a line of the form y = a + b * x, or vertical
>   and/or horizontal lines.

```
densityplot(e11$freq, 
            panel=function(x, ...) { 
              tab <- table(x)
              panel.barchart(names(tab), tab/length(x),
                             horizontal=FALSE)              
              panel.densityplot(x, plot.points=FALSE)},
            ylim=c(0, 0.3))
```

[image: lattice plot]

Comment: It works perfectly. Does `panel.density()` accept a second line? To create, for example, a comparison between the distribution of `e11$freq` and a normal curve?

Comment: You could use `panel.mathdensity()` to add a normal curve.